# How to extract 4dimensional data from a list of pandas dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy, tensor

I have a list of *500* *dataframes* (in the form of *.csv* files); 500 = 20(time) x 25(energy) bins. In other words, each dataframe is a measurement of *flux* at a single time and energy and is represented as *150x150* mesh grid corresponding to *x* and *y* spatial coordinates. However, I would like to transform these data into 4-d coordinates of the form **Flux(*x*, *y*, *t*, *E*)** such that I have new set of dataframes with columns *E* and rows *t* for any given (*x*,*y*) position.
I am not sure how to approach the problem. I would appreciate your help in giving me some sort of roadmap for doing this procedure.

Note:
The time and energy of each dataframe is in the name of the corresponding *.csv* file in the form  *time-5e+35-energy0.00023-position.csv* where *t*=-5 10^35 and *E*=0.00023.

What I know:
500 dataframes of 20tx25E must be converted to 22,500 dataframes of 150x150 coordinates. However, this is very time consuming and I am not sure if there is any other package in python3 that can do the job easier.

Comment: Your requirements as stated in the last paragraph of your question are a bit unclear. Are you looking to write 22,500 CSV files to the disk after transforming co-ordinates? Or do you want one CSV file with `(x,y,t,E) -> flux`?

Comment: Also, please provide the *specific* format of each of your 500 input CSVs. Are `x` and `y` coordinates listed in it? Or are these to be calculated from the array coordinates of the flux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that combines your files into one big Pandas dataframe of size `11,250,000` or `25 × 20 × 150 × 150`:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
import re
from datetime import datetime

pattern_file_name = re.compile(r'time-(.*)-energy(.*)-position.csv')

start_time = datetime.now()

result_df = None
for file_name in glob('time-*.csv'):

  # extract time and energy values from file name
  if not pattern_file_name.match(file_name):
    raise ValueError(f'file name {file_name} failed pattern match.')
  time_s, energy_s = pattern_file_name.findall(file_name)[0]
  time, energy = float(time_s), float(energy_s)
  
  print(f'Processing | {time_s} | {energy_s} |...')
  df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None)
  
  # assuming the CSV (i) has no headers (ii) is an array of 150x150...
  # ...floats with no missing or problematic values (iii) each row...
  # ...represents a fixed y-coordinate; adjust to your needs
  df.index.name = 'y'
  df = df.stack()
  df.index.rename('x', level=-1, inplace=True)
  df = df.swaplevel().sort_index().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'flux'})
  # df is now (x, y, f)
  # x and y will each vary from 0 to 149
  
  df.insert(0, 't', time)
  df.insert(0, 'E', energy)
  
  result_df = df if result_df is None else pd.concat([result_df, df])
  
result_df = result_df.set_index(['E', 't', 'x', 'y']).sort_index()
# result_df is now (E, t, x, y) -> flux
result_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=True)

final_time = datetime.now()
delta_time = final_time - start_time

print(f'Completed in {delta_time}')
```

The main steps are as follows:

- Loop over file names
- Extract `t` and `E` values from file name
- Read square matrix of flux values from file
- Transform `150 × 150` square matrix to Pandas dataframe of length `22,500`
- Add columns to keep track of `E` and `t`
- Append local result to a global, ever-increasing result vector
- Finally, leave the loop and save results to disk as CSV

The resulting CSV file will have 5 columns. The first four would represent `(E,t,x,y)` and the last column would be the value of the flux field at those co-ordinates.

Comment: Thank you @Salmonstrikess,